# In Swing, Is there a way to temporarily freeze repainting of a JComponent containment hierarchy?

Tags: java, performance, swing

If I have a bunch of custom JComponents in a Swing panel, and each of them can contain many other JComponents, is there a way to "freeze" repaints on the top level components and then unfreeze them, triggering a repaint?

I guess I am trying to do sort of a localized double-buffering.

Answer (score 3):

Also, *just in case* the reason you're doing this is because you are doing a bunch of GUI updates to components and are worrying about all of those automatically posted repaints(), don't. repaint() does not paint immediately, it posts a deferred repaint event to the AWT event queue, which will coalesce multiple repaints for a given region to avoid doing the same painting over and over.

Comment: Our problem is that we send enough of these events to hog the event thread to a point where the UI becomes unresponsive to user input. The only solution we found is to sleep between some updates, to give user interaction a chance to squeeze in, but we pay a cost. I'm trying to test whether somehow freezing and unfreezing can hasten things up a little.

Comment: Are these updates in response to user events (EDT), or to non-swing  events (eg background thread)?

Comment: Can you narrow down whether it is data processing occurring in the EDT or the actual repainting that is taking the time?

Answer (score 1):

Overriding `paint(Graphics)` to not do anything if a flag is set will prevent the painting from happening; you can also add your own double buffering by overriding to draw to a image.

You can enable double buffering on a per swing JComponent basis using that component's `setDoubleBuffered(boolean)` method, you don't need to do anything else if that's all you need.

---

Even if you disable painting at the top level component by overriding paint, it won't stop child components from painting if they are receiving events; you could replace the frame's contents with a static image ( created from calling paint with the graphics from a buffered image ).

Comment: it's better to override paintComponent() method.

And, if you just return from paintComponent(), will it keep previous image or just leave garbage?

Comment: Not always. paint calls paintComponent() and paintChildren() passing in the graphics for the off-screen buffer if double-buffering is enabled. If you want to change how a component paints itself without changing the behaviour of children, borders or double-buffering, then it's better to override paintComponent(), but that isn't what is being asked for here.